# impdp content=data_only, how to specify which tables to import first

Tags: oracle, impdp

I am trying to import my database using the command

```
impdp SYSTEM/password DIRECTORY=dmpdir DUMPFILE=database.dmp CONTENT=DATA_ONLY
```

This works at importing some parts of the data, however, I am getting an error:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.user_role_user_fk) violated -
>   parent key not found

Basically I need to import data from `USER` first before I can import data from `USER_ROLE`

Is there a way to specify order of operation or which table data to import first when using IMPDP?

EDIT: A bad solution I have found is to simply use the same `impdp` statement as above twice. By doing it twice, I can import both `USER` and `USER_ROLE`, however there has to be an easier way to this.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour, apparently; see MOS note 1062564.1. That refers out [to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL936), though that isn't clear that it applies in this situation. Are you able to disable the constraints before importing? In the past I've run a script to dynamically disable all constraints, and then re-enable them all afterwards.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Could you take your script and run it against a dmp file, though?

Comment: No, you'd run the script to disable; do the `impdp` (of all tables in one go); then run the script to re-enable. All of which could be done in a shell or batch script wrapper I suppose. The only alternative is what you've already tried, separate `impdp` runs to import them in the order you expect. You can't tell import the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could disable the constraints before importing, and re-enable them afterwards. You can do that with some dynamic SQL:

```
begin
  for r in (
    select 'ALTER TABLE "'||c.table_name||
      '" DISABLE CONSTRAINT "'||c.constraint_name||'"' as cmd
    from user_constraints c
    where c.constraint_type = 'R'
  )
  loop
    execute immediate r.cmd;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

After you've run that, e.g. via SQL*Plus using a heredoc in a shell script, you can then run your `impdp` command to import all of the tables in one go; and then run the same PL/SQL block but with `ENABLE` instead of `DISABLE`.

It's worth checking if you have any disabled constraints before you start. If you do the disable script could skip them based on their status, but the enable script wouldn't be able to tell whether they should be re-enabled or not; so you could either create a static enable script, or hard-code any exceptions you need.